# Preprocessor Directives to separate targets in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, c-preprocessor

I have 2 targets on my project one production and one stage with different configurations. 
I want in the code to be able to say

```
#if target == production
NSLog(@"production");
#elif target == stage 
NSLog(@"stage");
#endif
```

Can someone please tell me how can I do that?

Thank you,

~Sonic555gr

Comment: You could also make this target determination at runtime.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964630/xcode-project-how-to-detect-target-programatically-or-how-to-use-env-vars

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can define some Preprocessor Macros for each Target, like this...
[image: ...]

And then you can do something like this:

```
#ifdef PRODUCTION
   //some Code
#elif STAGE
   //some other Code
#else
   //more Code^^
#endif
```

But be carefull if you need it in Debug- and/or in Release-Build, you have to declare it there.