# How do I get the name of the target that is currently running in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, build

I have an Xcode project with several targets. Let's say the target names are `AppFreeVersion` and `AppPaidVersion`. They share the same codebase, but I want to implement some logic that is only for one of the targets.

Without modifying my scheme or build settings, is there a way to get the string of my current target name? The solution given [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6964630/361247) requires me to pass an environment variable in the build setting, which I don't want to do.

Comment: Maybe the following post can help
[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18783055/how-to-get-target-name/52966225#52966225)

Comment: Maybe the following question can help [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18783055/how-to-get-target-name/52966225#52966225)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about adding `${TARGET_NAME}` in your info.plist?

And I guess you already know how to get it

Obj-C

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:key_name];
```

Swift

```
let targetName = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary?[key_name] as String
```

Comment: Is this still available in Xcode 9? I added it to the Info.plist, but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 8):

Swift 3.0 Solution.

```
func getTargetName() -> String {
    return Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleName"] as! String
}
```

Comment: CFBundleName is not the Target name

Comment: Not CFBundleName, nor CFBundleDisplayName return target name, most likely they will be set in Info.plist to return product name.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer by Niko is still working for me on Xcode 12.2 and iOS 14.2

Here is a screenshot to better clarify what needs to be done in `Info.plist`:

[image: Info.plist screenshot]

You need to do this for each target's corresponding `Info.plist`

You don't even need to use `$(TARGET_NAME)` as the value, you can give your own custom unique values and check for those instead.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to add the target name property in the .plist file of respective target. then you can get it anywhere in the code.

```
print("Target Name = " + (Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["TARGET_NAME"] as! String))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfhtd.png)

Answer (score -1):

Just set Target name in your Scheme -> Environment Variables -> add Name and Value.
eg: targetName = "mytesttarget"

**Obj-c**

NSDictionary* envir = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment];

NSString* targetName = envir[@"targetName"];

**Swift**

let envir = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().environment

let targetName = envir["targetName"]

Answer (score -2):

On Swift 4.0

```
let targetName = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["TargetName"] as! String
```

Comment: this is not working, the app gets crashed. it did not found the "TargetName" key in  "Bundle.main.infoDictionary".