# Conditional compilation to check if I'm building a module or an app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a project with many different schemes. Is there a way to check if I'm building a "module scheme" or an "app scheme", without editing my build settings? Something like:

```
#ifdef SOME_SPECIFIC_APP_MACRO
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: see this for help : [How do I get the name of the target that is currently running in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36758639/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-the-target-that-is-currently-running-in-xcode/43306458)

Comment: That's interesting but I really need a conditional compilation.

Comment: Which way you prefer more? using pch files or build settings or configuration files?

Answer (score 0):

Say you have the following schemes named `Maintenance`, `Debug` and `Release`.

Assuming you have them properly set up with custom flags in your app `Build Settings > Active Compilation Conditions`.

In Swift you would simply do a conditional check like so:

```
#if Maintenance
    // ...
#elseif Debug || Release
    // ...
#else
    // ...
#endif
```

So, you do **need to add a flag for your scheme** in the Build Settings before using a conditional check for that specific scheme in your code. If you just look for a way to check the target though, you could easily grab that info from the plist I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, may be Xcode have such defines already, but you can use this:

```
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(inherited) MACH_O_TYPE=BIN_TYPE_${MACH_O_TYPE} BIN_TYPE_mh_execute=1 BIN_TYPE_mh_bundle=2 BIN_TYPE_mh_object=3 BIN_TYPE_mh_dylib=4 BIN_TYPE_staticlib=5 IS_APP=MACH_O_TYPE==BIN_TYPE_mh_execute IS_NOT_APP=MACH_O_TYPE!=BIN_TYPE_mh_execute
```

You can put it in **project** build settings, or put in xcconfig and attach to project configs.

Then you can use them in conditional compilation